# Is there a toki pona hieroglyphics font?

Tags: writing-systems, toki-pona

For the toki pona language there is a [writing system](http://tokipona.net/tp/janpije/hieroglyphs.php) where each word is replaced by a single logogram or hieroglyph. There is also a [web-based converter](http://sitelen-pona.herokuapp.com/) which allows you to enter a text in toki pona and converts it into a single PNG rendering in said hieroglyphs.

However, I was wondering if there was a way to directly produce texts in hieroglyphs, either as a font, or as a set of individual image files (ie one per word/hieroglyph), which could be used to render texts on webpages etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

toki!

a, mi jo e sitelen tawa toki pona. nimi ona li *linja pona*. sina ken anpa e ona kepeken [nimi tawa ni](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1SLofeaJqmyS3ZVTVcxMUtGNms/view).

Hi! Yes, I have a script for toki pona. Its name is *linja pona*. You can download it by [using this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1SLofeaJqmyS3ZVTVcxMUtGNms/view).

Comment: "Ah, I have images for toki pona. It's name is _linja pona_ ("good lines"). " Don't quite get the second part, but it's a link to a toki pona hierogplyphics font that one can use. -- maybe "you can download and use it here"?

Comment: Base on [this Meta discussion](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/113) I'm inclined to remove this answer if @KNTRO won't give a translation. Of course you can make the case in Meta that answers in conlangs should be allowed.

Comment: "Hi!

Yes, I have a script for Toki Pona. Its name is linja pona. You can download it by using this link".

tenpo ni la, sina pillin pona anu seme? 

Comment: How would I type in it?

Comment: [Here's an example, using GIMP 2.10.10.](http://oi63.tinypic.com/2j5xe1x.jpg)

@curiousdannii You forgot to add the ”” emoji in the edition. 